# Get the click result in outer class AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Good day to All! I'll try to describe my question. It's something in architecture scope...as I believe. So, let's start. 
I have an activity where the user can create new player or click `list` and get the list of already created players. So in activity.java I create `DatabaseHelper` and `SQLiteDatabase` and use it for `INSERT` (if new player) or `SELECT` (if the player choose the existing one). To fill the list I use `ListView` and `Adapter`. 
When user click (shortly) on the player name in the list, he get the `AlertDialog` with question "Do you want to proceed with player XXX?" If NO I simply cancel, if YES I take the name, create `intent` and start another `activity` with player name transferred `intent.putExtra("name", LoginDialog.selectedName))` to that another `activity`. That's quite good. But now I want to allow user to delete player. The idea is - after a long click user get `AlertDialog` with question "Do you really want to delete player XXX?" NO - it's clear - cancel. But how to cope with YES?

Roughly - after YES I have to connect to `DB` and perform `DELETE` query. How I tried:

```
public class DeleteDialog {
AlertDialog.Builder ad;
public static Context context;
public static String selectedName;
public DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
public SQLiteDatabase mSqLiteDatabase;

public void dialogOfSelectedName(Context context, String selectedName) {

    context = this.context;
    selectedName = this.selectedName;
    ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    ad.setTitle("Удаление игрока");
    ad.setMessage("Удалить игрока " + selectedName + "?");
    ad.setCancelable(true);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context, "mydatabase.db", null, 1);
    mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ad.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            mSqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM" + DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.NAME_COLUMN + " LIKE '" + selectedName + "'");
        }

    });

    ad.setPositiveButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = ad.create();
    alert.show();

    }
}
```

The problem is `selectedName` cannot be seen from overridden method `onClick` but I need it in the query. How to realize it? Or my approach is totally wrong? Please, help with advice. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make the variable as `final`. You will be able to access it in the `onClick` method.

Change

```
public void dialogOfSelectedName(Context context, String selectedName)
```

to

```
public void dialogOfSelectedName(Context context, final String selectedName)
```